# Understanding Mutability in F# : case study

Tags: f#, mutability

I'm a beginner in F#, and this is my first attempt at programming something serious. I'm sorry the code is a bit long, but there are some issues with mutability that I don't understand.

This is an implementation of the Karger MinCut Algorithm to calculate the mincut on a non-directed graph component. I won't discuss here how the algo works,
for more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm 
What is important is it's a randomized algorithm, which is running a determined number of trial runs, and taking the "best" run.

I realize now that I could avoid a lot of the problems below if I did construct a specific function for each random trial, but I'd like to understand EXACTLY what is wrong in the implementation below.

I'm running the code on this simple graph (the mincut is 2 when we cut the graph
into 2 components (1,2,3,4) and (5,6,7,8) with only 2 edges between those 2 components)

```
3--4-----5--6
|\/|     |\/|
|/\|     |/\|
2--1-----7--8
```

the file `simplegraph.txt` should encode this graph as follow
(1st column = node number, other columns = links)

```
1 2 3 4 7
2 1 3 4
3 1 2 4
4 1 2 3 5
5 4 6 7 8
6 5 7 8
7 1 5 6 8
8 5 6 7
```

This code may look too much as imperative programming yet, I'm sorry for that.

So There is a main for i loop calling each trial.
the first execution, (when i=1) looks smooth and perfect,
but I have runtime error execution when i=2, *because it looks some variables, 
like WG are not reinitialized correctly*, causing out of bound errors.

WG, WG1 and WGmin are `type wgraphobj`, which are a **record of Dictionary** objects
*WG1 is defined outside the main loop and i make no new assignments to WG1.*
[but its type is mutable though, alas]

I defined first WG with the instruction

```
let mutable WG = WG1
```

then at the beginning of the for i loop,
i write

```
WG <- WG1
```

and then later, i modify the WG object in each trial to make some calculations.
when the trial is finished and we go to the next trial (i is increased) i want to reset WG to its initial state being like WG1.
but it seems its not working, and I don't get why...

Here is the full code

MyModule.fs [some functions not necessary for execution]

```
namespace MyModule

   module Dict =
      open System.Collections.Generic
      let toSeq d = d |> Seq.map (fun (KeyValue(k,v)) -> (k,v))
      let toArray (d:IDictionary<_,_>) = d |> toSeq |> Seq.toArray
      let toList (d:IDictionary<_,_>) = d |> toSeq |> Seq.toList
      let ofMap (m:Map<'k,'v>) = new Dictionary<'k,'v>(m) :> IDictionary<'k,'v>
      let ofList (l:('k * 'v) list) = new Dictionary<'k,'v>(l |> Map.ofList) :> IDictionary<'k,'v>
      let ofSeq (s:('k * 'v) seq) = new Dictionary<'k,'v>(s |> Map.ofSeq) :> IDictionary<'k,'v>
      let ofArray (a:('k * 'v) []) = new Dictionary<'k,'v>(a |> Map.ofArray) :> IDictionary<'k,'v>
```

Karger.fs

```
open MyModule.Dict

open System.IO

let x = File.ReadAllLines "\..\simplegraph.txt";;
// val x : string [] =

let splitAtTab (text:string)=
    text.Split [|'\t';' '|]

let splitIntoKeyValue (s:seq<'T>) = 
    (Seq.head s, Seq.tail s)

let parseLine (line:string)=
    line
    |> splitAtTab
    |> Array.filter (fun s -> not(s=""))
    |> Array.map (fun s-> (int s))
    |> Array.toSeq
    |> splitIntoKeyValue

let y =
    x |> Array.map parseLine

open System.Collections.Generic
// let graph = new Map <int, int array>
let graphD = new Dictionary<int,int seq>()
y |> Array.iter graphD.Add
let graphM = y |> Map.ofArray //immutable 

let N = y.Length // number of nodes
let Nruns = 2 

let remove_table = new Dictionary<int,bool>()
[for i in 1..N do yield (i,false)] |> List.iter remove_table.Add

// let remove_table = seq [|for a in 1 ..N -> false|] // plus court

let label_head_table = new Dictionary<int,int>()
[for i in 1..N do yield (i,i)] |> List.iter label_head_table.Add

let label = new Dictionary<int,int seq>()
[for i in 1..N do yield (i,[i])] |> List.iter label.Add

let mutable min_cut = 1000000

type wgraphobj =
     { Graph : Dictionary<int,int seq>
       RemoveTable : Dictionary<int,bool>
       Label : Dictionary<int,int seq>
       LabelHead : Dictionary<int,int> }

let WG1 = {Graph = graphD;
          RemoveTable = remove_table;
          Label = label;
          LabelHead = label_head_table}

let mutable WGmin = WG1

let IsNotRemoved x = // 
    match x with 
    | (i,false) -> true
    | (i,true)  -> false

let IsNotRemoved1 WG i = //
    (i,WG.RemoveTable.[i]) |>IsNotRemoved

let GetLiveNode d = 
    let myfun x =
        match x with
        | (i,b) -> i
    d |> toList |> List.filter IsNotRemoved |> List.map myfun

let rand = System.Random()
// subsets a dictionary given a sub_list of keys
let D_Subset (dict:Dictionary<'T,'U>) (sub_list:list<'T>) = 
    let z = Dictionary<'T,'U>() // create new empty dictionary
    sub_list |> List.filter (fun k -> dict.ContainsKey k)
             |> List.map (fun k -> (k, dict.[k]))
             |> List.iter (fun s -> z.Add s)
    z

// subsets a dictionary given a sub_list of keys to remove
let D_SubsetC (dict:Dictionary<'T,'U>) (sub_list:list<'T>) =
    let z = dict
    sub_list |> List.filter (fun k -> dict.ContainsKey k)
                          |> List.map (fun k -> (dict.Remove k)) |>ignore
    z

// subsets a sequence by values in a sequence
let S_Subset (S:seq<'T>)(sub_list:seq<'T>) =
    S |> Seq.filter (fun s-> Seq.exists (fun elem -> elem = s) sub_list)

let S_SubsetC (S:seq<'T>)(sub_list:seq<'T>) =
    S |> Seq.filter (fun s-> not(Seq.exists (fun elem -> elem = s) sub_list))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let mutable u = 0
    let mutable v = 0
    let mutable r = 0
    let mutable N_cut = 1000000
    let mutable cluster_A_min = seq [0]
    let mutable cluster_B_min = seq [0]
    let mutable WG = WG1
    let mutable LiveNodeList = [0]

    // when i = 2, i encounter problems with mutability

    for i in 1 .. Nruns do
         WG <- WG1
         printfn "%d" i
         for k in 1..(N-2) do
             LiveNodeList <- GetLiveNode WG.RemoveTable
             r <- rand.Next(0,N-k)
             u <- LiveNodeList.[r] //selecting a live node
             let uuu  = WG.Graph.[u] |> Seq.map (fun s -> WG.LabelHead.[s] )
                                     |> Seq.filter (IsNotRemoved1 WG)
                                     |> Seq.distinct
             let n_edge =  uuu |> Seq.length
             let x = rand.Next(1,n_edge)
             let mutable ok = false //maybe we can take this out
             while not(ok) do
                  // selecting the edge from node u
                  v <- WG.LabelHead.[Array.get (uuu |> Seq.toArray) (x-1)]

                  let vvv = WG.Graph.[v]  |> Seq.map (fun s -> WG.LabelHead.[s] )
                                          |> Seq.filter (IsNotRemoved1 WG)
                                          |> Seq.distinct
                  let zzz = S_SubsetC (Seq.concat [uuu;vvv] |> Seq.distinct) [u;v]
                  WG.Graph.[u] <- zzz

                  let lab_u = WG.Label.[u]
                  let lab_v = WG.Label.[v]
                  WG.Label.[u] <- Seq.concat [lab_u;lab_v] |> Seq.distinct

                  if (k<N-1) then 
                      WG.RemoveTable.[v]<-true
                      //updating Label_head for all members of Label.[v]
                      WG.LabelHead.[v]<- u
                      for j in WG.Label.[v] do
                          WG.LabelHead.[j]<- u

                  ok <- true
                  printfn "u= %d v=%d" u v
             // end of for k in 1..(N-2)
         // counting cuts
         // u,v contain the 2 indexes of groupings
         let cluster_A = WG.Label.[u]
         let cluster_B = S_SubsetC (seq[for i in 1..N do yield i]) cluster_A // defined as complementary of A
         // let WG2 = {Graph = D_Subset WG1.Graph (cluster_A |> Seq.toList)
         //          RemoveTable = remove_table
         //           Label = D_Subset WG1.Graph (cluster_A |> Seq.toList)
         //          LabelHead = label_head_table}
         let cross_edge = // returns keyvalue pair (k,S')
             let IsInCluster cluster (k,S) =
                 (k,S_Subset S cluster)                    
             graphM |> toSeq |> Seq.map (IsInCluster cluster_B)

         N_cut <-
             cross_edge |> Seq.map (fun (k:int,v:int seq)-> Seq.length v)
                        |> Seq.sum
         if (N_cut<min_cut) then
             min_cut <- N_cut
             WGmin <- WG
             cluster_A_min <- cluster_A
             cluster_B_min <- cluster_B
    // end of for i in 1..Nruns


    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Description of the algo: (i don't think its too essential to solve my problem)

at each trial, there are several steps. at each step, we merge 2 nodes into 1, (removing effectively 1) updating the graph. we do that 6 times until there are only 2 nodes left, which we define as 2 clusters, and we look at the number of cross edges between those 2 clusters. if we are "lucky" those 2 clusters would be (1,2,3,4) and (5,6,7,8) and find the right number of cuts.
at each step, the object WG is updated with the effects of merging 2 nodes
with only LiveNodes (the ones which are not eliminated as a result of merging 2 nodes) being perfectly kept up to date.

WG.Graph is the updated graph

WG.Label contains the labels of the nodes which have been merged into the current node

WG.LabelHead contains the label of the node into which that node has been merged

WG.RemoveTable says if the node has been removed or not.

Thanks in advance for anyone willing to take a look at it !

Comment: Expand on "but it seems its not working"

Comment: is a mutable variable a pointer ? that would explain my woes

Comment: if I define first `let mutable WG=WG1` and then later i try `WG.Graph <- GraphD` , the compiler says WG.Graph is not mutable (although WG is). its a bit strange to me

Comment: Yes, in your case, mutable variable is a pointer. But this is only true for reference types.

Comment: `myfun` inside GetLiveNode duplicates the library function `fst: 'a * 'b -> 'a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It seems not working", because `wgraphobj` is a reference type, which is allocated on the stack, which means that when you're mutating the innards of `WG`, you're also mutating the innards of `WG1`, because they're the same innards.

This is precisely the kind of mess you get yourself into if you use mutable state. This is why people recommend to not use it. In particular, your use of mutable dictionaries undermines the robustness of your algorithm. I recommend using the F#'s own efficient immutable dictionary (called `Map`) instead.

---

**Now, in response to your comment about `WG.Graph <- GraphD` giving compile error.**

`WG` is mutable, but `WG.Graph` is not (but the *contents* of `WG.Graph` are again mutable). There is a difference, let me try to explain it.

`WG` is mutable in the sense that it points to some object of type `wgraphobj`, but you can make it, in the course of your program, to point at *another* object of the same type.

`WG.Graph`, on the other hand, is a field packed *inside* `WG`. It points to some object of type `Dictionary<_,_>`. And you *cannot* make it point to another object. You can create a different `wgraphobj`, in which the field `Graph` point to a different dictionary, but you cannot change where the field `Graph` of the original `wgraphobj` points.

In order to make the field `Graph` itself mutable, you can declare it as such:

```
  type wgraphobj = { 
    mutable Graph: Dictionary<int, int seq>
    ...
```

Then you will be able to mutate that field:

```
  WG.Graph <- GraphD
```

Note that in this case you *do not* need to declare the value `WG` itself as `mutable`.

However, it seems to me that for your purposes you can actually go the way of creating a new instance `wgraphobj` with the field `Graph` changed, and assigning it to the mutable reference `WG`:

```
  WG.Graph <- { WG with Graph = GraphD }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your very informative answer. i'll try to amend my code.